# Searching a column for a string and printing results in successive rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have one column with a list of .cpp filenames and another column representing test cases. I want to search all rows in the sheet that match a test case string and print the filename from that row.

```
column 1        column2 
--------       ------------    
file1.cpp      testcase1   
file2.cpp      testcase1   
file3.cpp      testcase3    
...             .......    
....            .......
```

So in the end I want an ouput that looks something like this:

```
Testcase1   Testcase2     
file4.cpp   file5.cpp    
file9.cpp   file8.cpp     
file5.cpp   file13.cpp
```

Here is the vba code:

```
Function fileToTest(Search_string As String, _
Search_in_col As Range)

Dim result As String   
Dim i As Long   
Dim j As Long   
Dim rArray(20) As String    
Dim rCnt As Long   
Dim rTmp As String   
Dim found As Long   
Dim testCases, Value As Variant   
Dim currentRow As Long    
Dim fCnt As Long    

  For i = 1 To Search_in_col.Count 'search each test case column    
     testCases = Split(Search_in_col.Cells(i, 1), ";")    
     For Each Value In testCases    
         If Search_string = Value Then    

        ActiveCell.Value = Search_in_col.Cells(i, 2).Value    
         ' write the next row after active cell. not sure how to do this
        End If   
      Next Value   
   Next i   


End Function
```

The function fails when I try to write to ActiveCell.Value

Comment: are you trying to call this from the sheet, like a UDF, because it won't work like that. Another way to approach it is to set up a `Sub` that loops through your range of Test Cases (column headers) and then `Filters` column2 of your data and then copies the visible cells under your header.

Comment: Yes, I am creating a formula to be called from a cell in a sheet. It works if I just want to return one result. But I will have many results to be returned. I just wanted to write all the results in successive rows after the active cell.

Comment: In that case, try this. Change `ActiveCell.Value = ...` to `ActiveCell.Offset(i-1).Value ...`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that - according to your comment - you want a User Defined Function - but then try to modify the worksheet. This is not possible, as the architecture of a UDF is that you cannot change anything to the worksheet, but only return a value with your function - which is then displayed. Also, in a UDF you're normally not allowed to read the values of any other cells than the ones handed over as parameters - else this will cause Excel to think there's a circular reference somewhere.

Therefore, I see the following three options:

1. Modify your UDF
2. Create a macro that fill all cells in one rush
3. Use Excel formulas only

Here are the details:

**1. Modify your UDF**

Assuming that you type in 'testcase1' in A1, build a UDF that you can call like this:

```
=FileToTestCase(A1,1,SourceSheet!A2:A100,SourceSheet!B2:B100)
```

The VBA definition of the UDF would then be something like this:

```
Public Function FileToTestCase(sTestCaseName as String, iElementNumber as Integer, _
    rngFileNames as Range, rngTestcases as Range) as String
    CodeToFigure out the iElementNumer_th entry for sTestCaseName
    FileToTestCase = YourResult
 End Function
```

This approach is however very inefficient, as you need to parse the source list every time. You can speed this up with some internal, module wide variables that you initialize in the first call and use later on - but then you need to take care to detect changes. Alternatively, you do it in one big array formula. However, both approaches are quite some effort.

**2. Create a macro that fill all cells in one rush**

Instead of a UDF, you have one macro that populates you all cells in one rush. If you want to update the content automatically, call the macro from a Worksheet_Change event - every time that the source data changes.

This code should do this:

```
Sub FillTestcases(rngFiles As Range, rngTestcases As Range, rngStartResult As Range)
    Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sTestCase As Variant
    Dim sFile As Variant
    Dim rngResult As Range
    Const csSeparator As String = "|"

    For lRow = 1 To rngFiles.Rows.Count
        sTestCase = rngTestcases(lRow, 1).Value
        sFile = rngFiles(lRow, 1).Value
        If d.Exists(sTestCase) Then
            d(sTestCase) = d(sTestCase) & csSeparator & sFile
        Else
            d.Add sTestCase, sFile
        End If
    Next

    Set rngResult = rngStartResult
    For Each sTestCase In d.Keys
        rngResult.Value = sTestCase
        rngResult.Font.Bold = True
        lRow = 1
        For Each sFile In Split(d(sTestCase), csSeparator)
            rngResult.Offset(lRow) = sFile
            lRow = lRow + 1
        Next sFile
        Set rngResult = rngResult.Offset(, 1)
    Next sTestCase
End Sub
```

Note that you'll need to add a reference to *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* in order to use the Dictionary class. Also note, that this code will not consolidate duplicates, so maybe you need to tweak it.

**3. Use Excel formulas only**

Assuming your filenames are in A1:A10, the test cases in B1:B10 and the list of test case names is in row 1, starting in column F, use this formula in F2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$10,-INT((LARGE(($B$1:$B$10=F$1)-ROW($B$1:$B$10)/10000,ROW(F1))-1)*10000)),"")
```

It is an array formula, so enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

HTH!